# setting Hours not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Does anyone have an idea why this simple code does not work?:

```
var formattedSched = new Date(sched).setHours(15);
```

I am simply trying to add a time to a calendar event in google calendar through apps script. I am even using basically the same sample on the w3 page for set hours. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp

But everytime I run the script to create an event in google calendar I get an error message that google thinks it is a number and not a date object. It works fine without the setHours() but with it, google thinks it's a number. Thanks

**Update**: Okay, I split out a test function to try and log what's happening:

```
function testsetcal() {

  var formattedSched = new Date(); Logger.log(formattedSched.setHours(15))

  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
  .createEvent('Commo', formattedSched, formattedSched);
}
```

and the Logger result **without** setHours is: `Wed Nov 21 08:12:33 PST 2012`

Logger result **with** setHours is: `1.35352881266E12`  which looks nothing like the example result on the w3 page.

**Update**: still not working and getting same logger result with setHours separated from main variable: `1.35352881266E12`

```
function testsetcal() {

  var formattedSched = new Date(); 
  var withHours = formattedSched.setHours(15);

  Logger.log(withHours);

  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
  .createEvent('Commo', withHours, withHours);
}
```

**UPDATE**: Okay wow - this is weird. I went to my google calendar to delete all the test events, at least just the ones I thought were successful. I then discovered that there were morte than I thought and some were set to 1500 - then I went back to the code and discovered that setHours() works on the outside of the google calendar create event like this:

```
function testsetcal() {  
  var formattedSched = new Date(); 

  formattedSched.setHours(15);

  Logger.log(formattedSched.setHours(15));

  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
  .createEvent('Commo', formattedSched, formattedSched);
}
```

So, this code set the hour to 1500, but that part of the code is to not be included in the creation of the event. Totally caught me surprised, but this seems to be the solution.

Comment: What is sched ? It appears that your Date object is not being properly constructed. I do not agree to the two answers that it is necessary to separate out the two statements.

Comment: I just posted an updated simplified test code - getting weird results compared to the w3 page. I'd be surprised if separating from the variable matters, but gonna give it a shot and report back

Comment: yeah, didn't work - trying all different kinds of formatting here and there and yet google still thinks the result is a number and not a date object - this should be so simple

Comment: Figured it out - some of my code test were including the setHours within the create event. Seems I need to set the Hours outside the create event then just call the variable into the create event. Very weird compared to other ways to call variabales in GAS.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, you are currently returning the setHours response to the var, try

```
var formattedSched = new Date(sched);
formattedSched.setHours(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate it out as in the example you referenced.

```
var formattedSched = new Date(sched);
formattedSched.setHours(15);
```

You are trying to implement the `setHours()` on a date object that has not been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I should go ahead and close this out. Thanks for the replies. The code that works for me to get an event into GCal with a time:

```
function testsetcal() {  
  var formattedSched = new Date(); 

  formattedSched.setHours(15);

  Logger.log(formattedSched.setHours(15));

  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
  .createEvent('Commo', formattedSched, formattedSched);
}
```

The `.setHours` must be outside the `.createEvent`.

Comment: i can't checkoff my own answer for 2 days, fyi, for some reason